# PHP file upload and zip on upload

Tags: php, upload, zip

Does anyone know of a good way to upload a file (.mp3 or .wav or .txt or .whatever) and zip this file before being moved to the directory?

So the user uploads a .mp3 file, before this file is moved to the specific directory it will be zipped and then moved.

Please advise.

Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a look at the Zip extension:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/zip.examples.php

I looked at the code you linked to (it would have been good if you included it in the question) and made a few changes:

```
$nameFile = $_FILES['file']['name'];
$tmpName = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
$download_folder = './files/';

$zip = new ZipArchive();
$fileconpress = $download_folder.$nameFile.".zip";

$conpress = $zip->open($fileconpress, ZIPARCHIVE::CREATE);
if ($conpress === true)
{
    $zip->addFile($tmpName);
    $zip->close();
    echo $fileconpress."<br/>";
    echo "yess !! Success!!!! ";
}
else echo " Oh No! Error";
```

The important part and likely what's causing your error is $download_folder.  You need to define the path of where you want to save the file.

I also removed the `fread()`, you can just load the file straight into the zip object with `addFile()`

Comment: Not working for me. I first need to save the temp files and after that I can compress them into a zip file. Directly saving the tmp file into a zip does not work for me. It only creates the zip file but it doesn't contain anything.

Comment: i know it's too late ..addfile as 2 arguments so probably u should do this '$zip->addFile($tmpName, $giveAfilename.jpg);'

Answer (score 0):

You can use PHP's ability to run shell commands and use them to make 3rd party software/your OS to zip your files for you. see - http://php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php

Or there is Zip extensions for php see - http://php.net/manual/en/book.zip.php

Comment: http://www.facebook.com/topic.php?uid=122203764461419&topic=337  I am using that but I do not understand where the file is then stored !! Could you help me?

Answer (score 0):

I think it's the best way to upload each type of file in zip exe espesialy when you don't know that your clients or users upload what kind of file.
for this way you should first set your direction in server where you want upload the file and then use:

```
<?php
$target_dir = '/www/yoursite.com/public_html/sth';
$ext = explode(".", $_FILES["filename1"]["name"]);
$ext = end($ext);
$newfilename = 'resume'. '.' .$ext;
$zip = new ZipArchive();
$zip->open('/www/yoursite.com/public_html/sth .'/'.'resume'.'.zip', 
ZipArchive::CREATE);
$zip->addFile($_FILES['filename1']['tmp_name'],$newfilename);
$zip->close();
?>
```

**just pay attention to my guide as your friend**

*when you want to use this code you should know these points:*

1. $target_dir-->your server address where you want upload your file
2. in this part of code i want to get the file extension until when i
   zip it keep the type of file

   ```
   $ext = explode(".", $_FILES["filename1"]["name"]);
   $ext = end($ext);
   $newfilename = 'resume'. '.' .$ext;
   ```
3. here i named my zip file in my server

   ```
   $zip->open('/www/yoursite.com/public_html/sth .'/'.'resume'.'.zip',
   ```
4. and in the end of code we get the upoloade file that i named here as
   "filename1(this is the name of your input in html)"

   ```
   $zip->addFile($_FILES['filename1']['tmp_name'],$newfilename);
   ```